# Where I can find in Dart SDK an implemention of the UnmodifiableSetView?

Tags: dart

Where I can find in Dart SDK an implemention of the `UnmodifiableSetView`?

In C# language exists `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableHashSet<T>`.
In Java language exists `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`.

But I cannot find anything similar in Dart SDK.
Where I can find it in Dart SDK?

P.S.

I use Dart language not for compiling it to the Javascript language.
I use it (as is) for the computations and I need `UnmodifiableSetView` but I connot find it in Dart SDK.

Answer (score 5):

There is an [UnmodifiableSetView](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/collection/1.1.0/index.html#collection/dart:pkg-collection-wrappers.UnmodifiableSetView) in `package:collection`.

This is an official implementation of an unmodifiable view of a Set created by the Dart team.
There is no similar class in the platform libraries. Unlike Java and C#, the Dart platform libraries are limited in size, and functionality that can just as easily be implemented in a separate library are made available as packages instead.

It's always a question about the trade-off between convenience (making everything immediately available) and size/discoverability (don't overwhelm the user).
If you are looking for functionality in, say, `dart:collection`, and doesn't find it, then the `package:collection` package is a good second location to look. Not all `dart:`-libraries have corresponding packages, but some do.